# Word for "on this side of the ocean"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word akin to 'cismontane' that refers to oceans or seas. Does this exist?

Answer (score 5):

*Cis-* is a particle like *trans-*, so you can use it to construct words with some confidence that readers will understand (or be able to work out) what you mean.  Not much confidence in this case, since *cis-* is uncommon in normal English.  That said, you could try

> **cis-oceanic**

(I am part of a small but easily amused group who would understand *cispondial* as meaning "on this side of the Atlantic" :-)

Comment: LLL OOO LLL !!!!!!  hah!  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30295/why-do-we-use-the-phrase-across-the-pond/30297#30297

Comment: I'm a bit humbled to realise that but for this page I personally *wouldn't* have known *cis-* as a meaningful English prefix. I know enough French that the sound automatically associates with "here", but I had no idea it could be used in composite English words. I'm now a fully signed-up member of your "small but easily amused group", ty. :)

Answer (score 2):

Keying off of [Rhodri's excellent answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31331/word-for-on-this-side-of-the-ocean/31387#31387), I remembered the word *transatlantic*:

> of, relating to, or situated on the other side of the Atlantic

Typing in *cisatlantic* shocked me because my spellchecker claimed it was a word. So I looked it up:

> on the same side of the Atlantic as the speaker

Oddly, there is *transpacific* but no *cispacific* in the same dictionary. But, in the case of talking between Europe and America, you can safely use *cisatlantic*.

Comment: It's uncommon enough that I wouldn't be entirely sure about being safe, but have +1 anyway.

Comment: +1 for being inspired to type in *cisatlantic* in the first place!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think such a *single* word for this, but there are alternative phrases:

> On my native shores

That should indicate pretty much that it is the native shores of the speaker or author.