# Who is responsible for calling the water between England and the United States "the pond?"

Tags: etymology, word-usage

I'd like to blame the English of course, but if there is an individual culprit that would also be satisfying. As an example of such an individual culprit, the American, T.S. Kuhn, coined the equally inappropriate "paradigm shift", according to [Collins English Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/paradigm-shift):

> **Word Origin**
>   C20: coined by T.S. Kuhn (1922–96), US philosopher of science

[Etymonline mentions *pond*](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=pond) is a

> Jocular reference to "the Atlantic Ocean" [that] dates from 1640s.

Is this the first use of *pond* in this sense? Was the first use "jocular"?

---

This question has been said to be a duplicate of [Why do we use the phrase 'Across the pond'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30295/why-do-we-use-the-phrase-across-the-pond), but that question, and the answers, focus on *why* the phrase "across the pond" was used, rather than on the origin of "the pond" (*not* "across the pond"). Also, that question, and so the answers, did not focus on the origin of the phrase, even if the answers did dally with the origin. Note that the [etymology](/questions/tagged/etymology) tag was added to that question *more than a year* after most of the responses; the one later response did not treat the origin of the phrase.

Comment: related - https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30295/why-do-we-use-the-phrase-across-the-pond

Comment: My impression has always been that the term arose during WWII when US-made aircraft would be shuttled across "the pond" to reach the war zone.

Comment: This question asks about the origin of "the pond", and why it is called that. The answers for the duplicate address the why of "across" the pond well enough, but do not address the origin, or the variants of the phrase "the pond", which latter is attested as early as 1612 (compare to the 1800s guessed by the answers for the duplicate).

Comment: @JEL I am amazed that "the pond" was used as early as 1612! Truth is, I was more interested in the origin of the usage than in its motivation, and until your post I had been quite happy to accept that that the motivation. was what we Yanks call British humor. I can't speak for the present, but I believe that in 1612 there was no such thing as British humor.

Comment: Yes...at first it looked as if the attested origin should be US (1838 NY use), but after I broadened the search to phrase variants, there were some surprises. In any case, the shenanigans with the edits for your question vis-a-vis the 'duplicate' are striking: the 'duplicate' was *not* an etymology question until the poster edited the tag in more than a year later; your original question was fine as you wrote it, and I'm tempted to roll it back, then add reasons it doesn't duplicate the purported 'duplicate' to get it re-opened. Later, though; off to other things now.

Comment: I appreciate your interest and effort, but I must warn you that I too am off to other things: my wife and I fly to England tomorrow for a two-week vacation.